# How to open multiple CSV files from a folder one by one, the one admin wants

Tags: python, tkinter

I have multiple .csv files in a directory and I want to open them one by one on user/admin demand which one he wants to open. And when he opened the file it displays on Tkinter interface in tabular format.

```
def open_att():
    ..........
    filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir="C:/Users/Ahmad Jan Ahmadi/Desktop/FYP-11 Final/Attendance/",title="Select Attendance File",filetypes=(("Csv Files","*.csv"),("All Files","*.*")))
    attend= pd.read_csv(filename)
    for row in attend:
        Id = row['Id']
        name = row['Name']
        date = row['Date']
        time = row['Time']
        tree.insert("", 100000, values=(Id, name, date,time))
```

When I run this program it gives me the error that:

> Exception in Tkinter callback
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:\Users\Ahmad Jan Ahmadi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\tkinter_*init*_.py", line 1699, in **call**
> return self.func(*args)
> File "C:\Users\Ahmad Jan Ahmadi\Desktop\FYP-11 Final\main.py", line 438, in open_att
> Id = row['Id']
> TypeError: string indices must be integers

First, I want to ask from the user which .csv file you want to open when he selects one of them then, how to display this file.

Comment: First let me tell the scenerio: i'm in a situation where first i want to open a csv file from a folder then i want to extract it nd use it in my program.                           
Code detail:I have opened a file with: file=filedialog.askopenfilename('directory',filetype(csv files))Then i read the file with:a=Pd.read_csv(file)Print(a)                             
When i print it gives me the result but can u tell me that how can i extract this file(its a small file 5x4) and use in my program..?

Answer (score 1):

I did this fast approach on my phone, needs few optimizations

```
import os
import glob


os.chdir("/mydir")
extension = 'csv'
all_filenames = [i for i in glob.glob('*.{}'.format(extension))]

for name in all_filenames:
   pattern = input("enter your desired file name: ")
   if pattern == name:
       file = name.readlines()
       print(file) 
   else:
       print("file does not exist")
```

Comment: thanks for u answer but it doesn't open a folder of files as i had open with(filedialog.askonpenfilename())command. i want to open a folder of csv files and select one of them and then extract it for the purpose to display it in the Tkinter frame.  let me tell the folder i want to open it opens but in extraction, it fails I'm not able how to extract a csv file.